# Theory: getter/setter function or global variable? C

Tags: c, global

I'm currently writing a C **LIBRABY** where I need to use a static void*.

In my first version I was putting all my functions that need to access my void* in the same C file it was declared in, like this:

main.c

```
int main()
{
  function_using_list();
}
```

foo.c:

```
void *list=NULL;

void *function_using_list()
{
  //stuff with list
}
```

In my second version I made a little get/set function so I can access my list through it from anywhere in my code:

foo.c

```
void   *getset_list(void nlist, int action)
{
   static void  *list = NULL;

   if (action == 1)
     return (list)
   else
     list = nlist;
}
```

What are the pros and cons of these two different designs? Is the second one Thread-safe?

**PS:** I just realized that I forgot something in my question: This code is meant to be used as a library.

Comment: Do not use global variables. Always ends in tears. Get a +1 for being cute

Comment: I'm not seeing how the `getset_list` function helps anything. Anywhere you use it, you need to have it declared, and anywhere you have it declared, you could have instead declared `list`.

Comment: @EdHeal: I don't see any substantial difference in the safety of the two options presented here...

Comment: The only thing I can see is that in the `getset_list` version nobody can take the address of the `list` variable and mess around with it when you don't expect it. They at least have to go through `getset_list`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Consider if another library has a global variable `list`?

Comment: First parameter 'nlist' should be of void* type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first approach gives you less control than the second, because anyone can read or change the global variable at any time - including the time before it has been initialized.

The second approach, on the other hand, lets you decide what to do when the variable has not been initialized, so if you need to use global state, the second approach is preferred.

There is a third approach - making a static variable at the level of the translation unit, and adding two separate functions - one for getter, and one for setter. This would free you up from having to pass `action=1` or `action=0`:

```
static void *list = NULL;
void* get_list() {
    return list;
}
void set_list(void* newList) {
    list = newList;
}
```

Neither approach gives you thread safety "for free". However, the approaches where `static` is inside a function gives you an easy way to implement thread safety, while the first one leaves it up to the caller to deal with synchronizing access to the global.

Comment: Using static global variables is a nice idea, as long as other files (TUs) used in the project are consistent with this practice. I.e. having a non-static global variable with the same name in some other file will generate compiler error.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Actually, this code is meant to be used as a Library, does it change your answer?

Comment: @Antoninarto If the library is for in-house use, then both the second and third approaches are OK. If it is for external distribution, I would strongly suggest using the third approach (i.e. with two functions) because it is more intuitive for outsiders.